# Evaluating a limit of a Fourier series

Tags: limits, fourier-series

I have a Fourier series representation of a solution to the heat equation, given by

$\displaystyle u(t,x) = \\ \displaystyle\sin \omega t + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\omega\left\lbrack \frac{\omega\sin \omega t + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\left( \cos \omega t - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right)}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} \right\rbrack\cos\left\lbrack \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi x \right\rbrack}.$

How would one go about computing

$\displaystyle \lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty}{u(t,0)}$

explicitly?

Comment: What is the differential equation?

Comment: The heat equation in one dimension.

Comment: So $u_t = u_{xx}$ ? I'm wondering where $\omega$ came into this...

Comment: Correct. Angular frequency is present due to a boundary condition $u(t,1) = \sin\omega t$.

Comment: What is the other boundary condition? It just looks like you'll run into trouble. Without doing any heavy lifting, what is $\lim_{\omega\to\infty} \sin \omega t$? Unless the infinite sum will be cancelling this stuff out, you're not going to have a limit.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u(t,0)}{\partial x} = 0$. That's exactly what I was thinking. But I plotted it and it looked like it could be potentially expressed in closed-form.

Comment: You plotted the left endpoint as a function of $\omega$ and it went to a fixed limit? Interesting. For fixed $t$? Was it uniformly continuous or point wise?

Comment: No, I meant the entire solution. Though if you consider the frequency increasing indefinitely, the time for heat transfer is reduced. Perhaps $u(t,0) \rightarrow 0$ as $\omega\rightarrow\infty$ sounds reasonable?

Comment: It is an interesting condition. Fast oscillations would make me think physically that they should cancel at the far boundary, but with no-flux conditions where does the pumped in energy go?

I'll need to think about it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quicker method to obtain the same result is as follows. Firstly, merge the $\sin\omega t$ term with the rest of the Fourier series. This is achieved by noting that the coefficient of $\sin\omega t$ is unity, and so the Fourier series of unity in terms of the spatial variable $x$ may be employed:

\begin{align*}
\sin\omega t &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{4\left( -1 \right)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)\pi}\sin\omega t\cos\left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x\right]} \\
&= - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\sin\omega t\cos\left\lbrack \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi x \right\rbrack}.
\end{align*}

Thus

\begin{align*}
u(t,x) &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\omega\left\lbrack \frac{\omega\sin\omega t + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\left( \cos\omega t - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right)}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} - \frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega} \right\rbrack\cos\left\lbrack \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi x \right\rbrack}.
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
u(t,0) &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\left\lbrack \frac{\omega^{2}\sin\omega t + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\omega\left( \cos\omega t - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right)}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} - \sin\omega t \right\rbrack} \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\frac{\omega^{2}\sin\omega t + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\omega\left( \cos\omega t - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right) - \left( \omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4} \right)\sin\omega t}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}}} \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{4( - 1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\frac{\left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\omega\left( \cos\omega t - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right) - \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}\sin\omega t}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}}}.
\end{align*}

To determine the limit as $\omega \rightarrow \infty$ of $u(t,0)$, consider each term separately:

\begin{align*}
\text{Limit 1:} && \lim_{\omega \rightarrow \infty}\left\lbrack \frac{\left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\omega\left( \cos\omega t \right)}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} \right\rbrack, \\
\text{Limit 2:} && \lim_{\omega \rightarrow \infty}\left\lbrack \frac{\left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}\omega\left( - e^{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}\pi^{2}t} \right)}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} \right\rbrack, \\
\text{Limit 3:} && \lim_{\omega \rightarrow \infty}\left\lbrack \frac{- \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}\sin\omega t}{\omega^{2} + \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{4}\pi^{4}} \right\rbrack,
\end{align*}

which all tend to zero, giving

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty}{u(t,0)} = 0
\end{equation*}

as required.

Comment: a nice and simple solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

Funny enough, but there is no problem with $\sin\omega t$ at $\omega\to\infty:\boxed{\,\,\, \lim_{\omega\to\infty}u(t;0)=0\,\,}$

To show this, let's consider
$$u(t;0)=\sin\omega t+\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{4(-1)^{n}}{(2n - 1)\pi}\omega \frac{\omega\sin \omega t + ( n - \frac{1}{2} )^2\pi^2( \cos \omega t - e^{- ( n - \frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2t})}{\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4} $$
$$=\sin\omega t+\frac{2\omega^2\sin\omega t}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}$$
$$+2\pi\omega\cos\omega t\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}(n - \frac{1}{2})}{\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}+2\pi\omega\cos\omega t\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{- ( n - \frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2t}}{(n - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}\qquad(1)$$
Evaluating the last term:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{\omega(-1)^{n}e^{- ( n - \frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2t}}{(n - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}<2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{\omega e^{- ( n - \frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2t}}{\omega^2 }<\frac{\operatorname{Const}}{\omega}\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,\omega\to 0$$
To evaluate the third term we notice that
$$\frac{1}{2}S=\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}(n - \frac{1}{2})}{\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}(n - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}$$
To evaluate the sum $S$ we use a standart approach: integrating in the complex plane along a big circle of the radius $R\to\infty\,$ the function $f(z)=\frac{(z - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +( z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$:
$$\oint\frac{(z - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +( z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}dz$$
The integrand declines rapidly enough at $R\to\infty$, so $\oint\to0$.
On the other hand
$$\oint\frac{(z - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +(z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}dz=2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}\frac{(z - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +(z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}=0\qquad(2)$$
where we take all residues lying inside the circle. We have simple poles of $\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$ at $z=\pi n, n=0,\pm1,\pm2...$ with residues $(-1)^n$ (and evaluating these residues we get the sum $S$). We also have four poles at $\omega^2 +( z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\,\Rightarrow\, z_k=\frac{\sqrt\omega}{\pi}e^{\pi i/4+\pi i k/2}+\frac{1}{2}, \,k=0,1,2,3$. What is important for us is that $z_k$ contain non-zero imaginary parts: $z_k = i\sqrt\omega\alpha_k+\sqrt\omega\beta_k; \,\alpha_k,\,\beta_k\neq 0$ - some real constants.
From $(2)$ we get:
$$S=-\sum_{k=0,1,2,3}\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_k}\frac{(z - \frac{1}{2})}{\omega^2 +(z - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$$
But
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin z_k}=\frac{2\pi i}{e^{-\alpha_k\sqrt\omega+i\beta_k\sqrt\omega}-e^{\alpha_k\sqrt\omega-i\beta_k\sqrt\omega}}$$
so, it is exponentially small ($\sim e^{-|\alpha_k|\sqrt\omega}$) at $\omega\to\infty$. Therefore, $S\to0$, and the third term tends to zero as well.

To evaluate the second term in $(1)$, we consider the integral
$$\oint\frac{1}{(z - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +(z-\frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}dz=0$$
The evaluation is similar to the evaluation of the third term, but in this case there is also a simple pole at $z=\frac{1}{2}$. The residue in this pole is
$$\operatorname{Rez}_{z=\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{(z - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +(z-\frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}\,\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}=\frac{\pi}{\omega^2\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\pi}{\omega^2}$$
Given that other four terms (residues) are exponentially small, we get for the second term in $(1)$
$$\frac{2\omega^2\sin\omega t}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n - \frac{1}{2})\big(\omega^2 +( n - \frac{1}{2})^4\pi^4\big)}\to \frac{2\omega^2\sin\omega t}{\pi}\cdot\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{\omega^2}\Big)=-\sin\omega t$$
And this term cancels the first term, providing $\lim_{\omega\to\infty}u(t;0)=0$.

The numeric check at WolframAlpha confirms this conclusion.

Comment: I figured that was what had to end up happening. Nice work!

Comment: @Gregory, thank you! Your analysis inspired me to do the evaluation - to find out whether it is the case from the math side ;)

Comment: Thank you for all of this work! Would you say this conforms with my physical interpretation of the situation? A heat source $u(t,1) = \sin\omega t$ whose frequency $\omega\rightarrow\infty$ does not transfer any net heat, giving $\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty}{u(t,0)} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct. I guees that if we have a highly oscillating source of the heat, the average temperature on the bound tends to zero, and not heat is being transmitted deeper into the object

Comment: @Username Taken Yes, the answer is positive. Please see the comment above. I can also add that mathematically the heat transmission is exponentially small at $\omega\to\infty$. So, mathematically, high frequency oscillations lead to the exponential decay of the transmitted heat (and not to, for example, some power of $\frac{1}{\omega}$)